# Dojo emit click event to dojox.mobile.ToolBarButton

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

Im trying to fire a click event on a tool bar button Dojo 1.8.1.

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ToolBarButton" class="backButton" moveTo="cartView" transition="slide">
```

I have tried

```
function backClick(){
var backButton = dojo.query(".backButton", dojo.byId(currentView.id))[0];
writeLog("backClick::"+backButton);
if(backButton){
    var backDijit = dijit.registry.byId(backButton.id);
    writeLog("backDijit::" + backDijit.id);
    writeLog("emit Click");
    backDijit.emit("click", {bubbles:true});
    writeLog("emit mousedown");
    backDijit.emit("mousedown",{bubbles:true});
    writeLog("emit mouseup");
    backDijit.emit("mouseup",{bubbles:true});
    writeLog("touchstart");
    backDijit.emit("touchstart");
    writeLog("touchEnd");
    backDijit.emit("touchend");


}else{
    //Exit App notification
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}

}
```

mousedown/mouseup combo works on the browser.
But on the device it does not work(Android).  What is the event that i have to send to 'click' the button on a device?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the sequence of events that will activate the toolbar button 'click' on a touch device is touchstart followed by touchend.

I suppose that your example do not work because the synthetic touch events that you are emitting do not contains any data, which fails the different methods that handle it.

Another way to trigger the click handler of the toolbar button would be to call its _onClick method.

Comment: I cant seem to call the _onClick of the button widget, im guessing since the action listener is created in the background (the moveTo flag) with the dojo.on listener, the _onClick does not do anything.

Comment: If your primary goal is to perform the transition defined for you back button, you can also do this by executing the performTransition method of the view (instead of retrieving the back button to emulate a click on it, retrieve the view and execute its performTransition method). What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: If the app is 4 views down, it was just easier to fire the backbutton since it already has the name of the previous view written to it.  The only option that i see is if this wont work is to have to create an array of past view names to manually backtrack the app.  The dojo.history looked interesting, but not sure if it will handle view transitions.

Comment: In the example you've given, you're using moveTo to specify the view to transition to when clicking the toolbar button. In this case, you can always retrieve the value of the moveTo attribute from the button... But it seems that your real use case is different. Maybe you could explain it here in more details ?